# Application for Scheduling Tweets

Tags: mac, macos, twitter

There seem to be several Mac applications that will send tweets scheduled in advance, but I'm having a hard time figuring out which is good. The bulk of the Google results are more than a year old.

Does anyone have any firsthand experience, and can you recommend something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoot suite for the iPad. But I'm not a heavy user.

Comment: Thanks. HootSuite isn't ideal -- I'm using the website -- but it definitely does schedule tweets, and you can use it for free in a limited way.